# Stale element exception python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am retrieving my link using the following code:

```
os.environ['MOZ_HEADLESS'] = '1'
binary = FirefoxBinary('C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe', log_file=sys.stdout)
self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary, executable_path='C:/chromedriver/geckodriver')

self.driver.get(link)
```

Next, I call:

```
xpath=".//a[@class='tileLink']"
ignored_exceptions = (NoSuchElementException, StaleElementReferenceException,)

your_element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 30, ignored_exceptions=ignored_exceptions).until(
                expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpath)))
```

and then

```
links = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//a[@class='tileLink']")
for link in links:
     href_ = link.get_attribute("href") # <<-- Error ehre
```

and `link.get_attribute(attribute)` throws the stale element exception.

Now, given the `WebDriverWait` I thought I would avoid this issue, yet it persists.

I am tempted to take the page source, once it has loaded, and throw it into lxml to avoid this issue completely.

The time the passes between establishing `links` and iterating over the links is a second at most.

Has anyone else experienced an issue like this, and found a solution?

Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: I assume that some of the retrieved elements in the `links` list don't hold any `href` attributes, so you should use a `try`-`except` block to get rid of this problem.

Comment: @Szabolcs Thanks, but then the exception would not be `StaleElement`, it would be something else completely. I do not think this is accurate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have understood your question you need to get the `href` attribute from all the elements identified with the *xpath* `//a[@class='tileLink']`. To achieve that you can use the following code block :

```
# xpath=".//a[@class='tileLink']"
# ignored_exceptions = (NoSuchElementException, StaleElementReferenceException,)
# links = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 30, ignored_exceptions=ignored_exceptions).until(expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpath)))
links = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 30).until(expected_conditions.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='tileLink']")))
for link in links:
     print(link.get_attribute("href"))
```

Comment: I may be an idiot, but I don't see how your code is different than mine?

Comment: It seems the only fix is to the xpath select using webdriverwait, in place of find_elements_by_xpath, right?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with some movable buttons on the page being stale.

How about something like:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

hrefs = []
for index, link in enumerate(links):
    attempts = 0
    while True:
        try:
            for action in range(0, 10):
                ActionChains(context.browser). \
                    move_to_element(links[index]).click().perform()
                href_ = link.get_attribute("href")
                if href_:
                    hrefs.append(href_)
                    break
            break
        except StaleElementReferenceException:
            attempts += 1
            if attempts > 10:
                break
```

I realise this is a very crude (primitive, even) solution, and assumes that the element becoming "un-stale" is a timing issue.
I'm also not that good with Python, so this may need some tweaking...

Thinking about it, since those elements are links, perhaps you don't want to click them, in which case delete the `click()` bit from the ActionChains line, or perhaps change it to `context_click()`.